# Using map reduce to perform address validation in dataset

Tags: validation, hadoop, parallel-processing, mapreduce

I have a data set from that contains addresses from 150 countries all around the world and your task is to verify them, the data is stored in 3 fields – Address Line,  City, ZIP code. What I also have available is address verification solution for each country, but the data set does not include the country code. The task is to design logic that will process the data and find the country for each record, so they can be ran through a validation component. What is the most efficient way.

As running all the 150 address verification components against each record is not considered efficient, I am considering parallel processing and using map reduce. My logic is as follows:

A possible solution would require a distributed approach and parallel processing in a map/reduce framework, for example:

- The Data-set could be broken into equal “chunks” one for each country that would be processed in parallel on different clusters.
- A mapping function operating on each chunk could map each address with its respective country code.
- A shuffling stage will aggregate all the outputs of the mapper functions by country
- Finally reduce functions operating on each country chunk will validate the address for their respective country resulting with only the valid address for each country.

I don't know if this is making any sense or if it's even possible to achieve this functionality with map/reduce. I just thought this solution because i remember some courses we did but in my uni days regarding cloud computing, parallel processing and big data. Any suggestions or different approaches are more than welcome... this is for a job interview thanks...

Comment: I added the `hadoop` tag because it should attract more attention than the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapReduce can be useful for combining large datasets, however in your case you have one large dataset (the addresses) and one tiny dataset (the countries). In this case, a Map-only MapReduce job will be fine, and you'd do the following:

1. Read the addresses dataset as your Mapper input.
2. Read the countries dataset into memory (for example as a `HashMap`), using MapReduce's [cache functionality](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setCacheFiles(java.net.URI[])).
3. Do a `HashMap` lookup on each address record as you process it to associate it with its country.
4. Apply your validation logic and output.

Having said all that, if I was to do this I'd definitely use Apache Spark rather than MapReduce.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! so if I got it right, after the address to country association step I wont need to do a reduce to validate?

Comment: No, there's no need for a Reduce anywhere here. Just do your validation in the Mapper after looking up the country. You only need to Reduce if you need to compare/aggregate similar records, but in your case every record is processed independently.